# Redirection to different landing page according to city - Wordpress Site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect, geolocation

I am new to Website development so I want to redirect people from specific cities to the specific landing page and all the rest to normal homepage in a WordPress site. I have to do this for a client. is there a sample blog or code that can help me I got the longitude and latitude via script I want to detect the location automatically and then redirect according to the city.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else { 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}

function showPosition(position) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>" +
  "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

however, I don't know how to proceed from here. (TT)

Comment: The code you have there, is client-side JavaScript - so you would have to load a page executing this code first, and only then can you redirect elsewhere. Either by sending those lat/long values to PHP and then having that redirect somewhere; or by changing the location directly using JavaScript. But you will of course need an additional step that "translates" your lat/long into a specific city first of all - which will likely require using some additional external API.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an article or a blog that can help me set up the whole thing?